# How can I update widget from CardSection?

Tags: add-on, gmail-addons

I am trying to update widget from CardSection, but I have no ideas to do this task

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mizle.jpg.

Anyone have an idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.  I was trying to find the reference to this, but I cannot find it.  I remember reading it though.  You cannot update any part of a card that you have already rendered.  You can only push a new card onto the stack or update the card in place with another card.